# Access NgModel Object (not value) in component file (typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am working with `[(ngModel)]` - Two way binding.

HTML -

```html
<input
  type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="emailInput" 
  #toemail="ngModel" 
  [email]="true" 
  [style.color]="toemail.invalid && toemail.touched ? 'red' : ''"
/>
```

TS -

```js
public emailInput: string;
```

In component file I can get input value as string in variable **`emailInput`**.

But I want [ngModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) object in some variable in component typescript file. Although I can access it in html file with reference variable **`toemail`**, but wants it in component file.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: I don't understand `I want ngModel object in some variable`. What is `ngModel object` supposed to be?

Comment: @Jeremy - NgModel --> { NgModel } from "@angular/forms"

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) for that.

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { NgModel } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  //...
})
export class SomeComponent {
  @ViewChild('toemail', {static: true}) toemail: NgModel;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.toemail) // ngModel
  }
}
```

This will give you access to the `ngModel`

Comment: im sure there's other ways .. but this is a documented use of ViewChild